# Unix alternative for LDAPAdmin

Tags: unix, solaris, openldap

I am looking for a Unix alternative for LDAPAdmin(Windows). Our OpenLDAP runs in Solaris and I can't browse it directly from Windows due to firewalls which won't be relaxed. Currently I use crude JNDI programs(ran from Solaris) to fish out data which we want.

I cannot directly query OpenLDAP in Solaris due to user permissions which are lacking and won't be granted. Thoughts? :)

[Btw no GUI necessary. I access Solaris thru Putty]

Answer (score 1):

The openldap utils should be helpful for this. I use ldapsearch and ldapmodify. Just make sure you install the ldap client and ldap utilities packages as well.

Comment: I will check this out the first thing I am back in office next week. Thank you!

Comment: The other super-helpful tool from this package is `ldapvi`, which opens up the tree in an editor. (Use an appropriate search pattern, like `ldapvi (uid=me)` to avoid pulling the whole directory in.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your LDAP tree from a shell, you need [`shelldap`](http://projects.martini.nu/shelldap)! It gives you a history-keeping tab-completing directory interface to an LDAP server, and most importantly, it's fun to say. (Shelldap! Shelldap! Shelldap!)

If you have a local X server (like [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/)) & SSH forwarding, you can always run GUI programs remotely. I can highly recommend [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) though on Solaris you will probably need to install it as an Eclipse plugin.